# Setting CORS headers in Azure mobile services Javascript backend

Tags: javascript, android, azure, cors, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to register an android emulator (Genymotion) to an Azure notification hub, but during debugging I see that there is an error `Refused to get unsafe header "Location"` which from what I have gathered is a CORS issue. Now, is it possible in the javascript backend to set the `Access-Control-Expose-Header` to include Location?

First of all, is my line of reasoning correct, or am I missing something because of which the `XMLHttpRequest` just won't let me query on the Location header.

Btw, I am running the app on cordova/Ionic and when installed on my device, the app successfully registers with the hub, but I am facing the above issue with the emulator.

Any help will be much appreciated!